# The file name must end with .xml or .png

Tags: android-studio, archivo, compilador

Estoy recibiendo el siguiente error:

> C:\Users\Alfonso\AndroidStudioProjects\Focus\app\src\main\res\drawable\desktop.ini:
>   Error: The file name must end with .xml or .png

Cuando reviso la dirección que me da el error en mi carpeta de drawable me da el siguiente texto en un bloc de notas:

> [LocalizedFileNames] mission.png=@mission.png,0
>   balance_24.png=@balance_24.png,0

Ya he borrado estas imágenes de mi carpeta, pero el error persiste. También ya comprobé de que no exista ningún archivo oculto `Desktop.ini`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41011739/error-the-file-name-must-end-with-xml-or-png

Comment: prueba clic en el menu file->invalidate cache/ restart

Comment: No funciono.. Y mi problema es diferente al que esta en el link de Juan, ya que yo no tengo ningun archivo que no sea de los especificados..

Comment: No dices nada sobre el contexto, ni siquiera dónde te da el error. ¿Qué tienes en tu carpeta `drawable`? ¿Tienes otro tipo de archivos allí? Hablo de todas las carpetas `drawable`.  ¿Revisaste también desde fuera de Android Studio?

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow,  podrías por favor colocar el fragmento i/o fragmentos de código que te dan el problema?, de esta forma se te podría dar  una mejor solución, saludos @AlfonsoBriceño

Answer (score 0):

elimina el archivo strings.rng que esta en la carpeta  de tu proyecto c:\TuProyecto\app\src\main\res\values

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]